# How can I override NHibernate's Class mapping Where clause?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an NHibernate mapping that looks like this:

```
<class name="Customer" table="Customer" where="Region=0">
    ...
</class>
```

I cannot change this mapping without serious impact on other areas of the application.

Is there a way I can query for Customers not in Region 0, avoiding NHibernate appending a `(where Region=0)` to all of the SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an OR clause in the method where you need customers from all regions

```
OR Region <> 0
```

Which technically is equivalent to take customers from all regions.

Comment: Not sure this can be done, or at least with `QueryOver` and `HQL` that I tried. The `Where` clause is always appended with a `AND` operator. You can't simply add a `OR` clause to that.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but you may give a try to an Interceptor :

```
public class SqlRegionInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor, IInterceptor
{

    NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        return sql.Replace("Region=0", "Region<>0");
    }
}
```

Then when you need to retrieve your non Region=0 customers :

```
var interceptor = new SqlRegionInterceptor ();
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor))
{
    var customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>.List();
    ...
    session.Close();
}
```

Use with care when dealing with complex queries. You may quickly end-up replacing unwanted SQL parts.
Note that this will no retrieve Customer with NULL Region.